# Showing check box label with single quotes

Tags: ruby

Not able to show jQuery mobile check box with values like aa''a@a.com

```
@contact_info = [{:source_id=>40021, :object=>"148302514605161.2", :account_number=>"332950", :contact_type=>"E", :contact_value=>"aa''a@a.com", :sequence=>"1"}, {:source_id=>40021, :object=>"148302514605162.2", :account_number=>"332950", :contact_type=>"E", :contact_value=>"asdf@asd.org", :sequence=>"2"}, {:source_id=>40021, :object=>"148302514605163.2", :account_number=>"332950", :contact_type=>"E", :contact_value=>"dog@g.com", :sequence=>"3"}, {:source_id=>40021, :object=>"148302514605164.2", :account_number=>"332950", :contact_type=>"E", :contact_value=>"gh'g@ff.bn", :sequence=>"4"}, {:source_id=>40021, :object=>"148302514605165.2", :account_number=>"332950", :contact_type=>"F", :contact_value=>"2579525795", :sequence=>"5"}]
```

In .erb file

```
 <table id="previous_email_fax_list">
      <% if @contact_info. size > 0 %>
      <% @contact_info.each do |contact|%>  
        <tr>
          <td style="border:1px solid black;"> 
            <div class="email_fax_check">
              <input type="checkbox" name="<%= contact.contact_value %>" id="<%= contact.contact_value %>"  class="custom" />
              <label for="<%= contact.contact_value %>"><br/></label>
            </div>
            <div class="email_fax_label">
              <% if contact.contact_type == "E" %>
                <%= contact.contact_value %>
              <% elsif contact.contact_type == "F" %>
                <%= number_to_fax(contact.contact_value) %>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% else %>
        <tr>
          <td align='center'>
             No email addresses or fax numbers found for this account
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </table>
```

I am getting `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: for='gh'g@ff.bn']`

Answer (score 0):

I copied this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<%= contact.contact_value %>" id="<%= contact.contact_value %>"  class="custom" />
          <label for="<%= contact.contact_value %>"><br/></label>
```

and added it to an existing app view, adding a variable, removing `contact.` and removing all of the double quotes to make a test:

```
<% contact_value = "'gh'g@ff.bn'" %>
          <input type="checkbox" name=<%= contact_value %> id=<%= contact_value %> class="custom" />
          <label for=<%= contact_value %>><br/><%= contact_value %></label>
```

I get:

[image: checkbox image]

without any errors. Give it a try without any quotes around the `<%= contact.contact_value %>` in the view code.